# 2 developers under 1 xcode

Tags: xcode

in my xcode, i upload apps to the store with my own developer account.
in the same xcode same mac,i have to upload now app(ad-hoc) to the place i work at-with their account .

my question is, how do i make to whole process to be under the company development account?
the distribution/development file that i create to that app,are the one that promise that ?

Comment: I didn't understand a thing...

Comment: Is your shift key broken? If you'd used proper punctuation, you wouldn't have been forced to add in some irrelevant code at the bottom of the question.

Comment: 2 developers, 1 xcode ... I had some freaky flashbacks reading the title like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Apple developer portal, create and download provisioning profiles under the company and use them for the company app.

Hope it helps